# Ошибка KeyError в модели ML

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Это код машинного обучения, обучения двух моделей градиентного бустинга и одной модели компьютерного зрения. В этом коде пытался реализовать функцию тестирования всех трех моделей def test_models. Но она выдает ошибку KeyError. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.`

```
import cv2
from cmath import cos
import sys
print(sys.path)
import catboost
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import math
import pandas as pd
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
SYMBOL = 'EURUSD'
MA_PERIODS = [i for i in range(45, 300, 35)]
MARKUP = 0.00002
START_DATE = datetime(2015, 1, 1)
TSTART_DATE = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
STOP_DATE = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
FSTOP_DATE = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK = pd.DatetimeIndex([])

import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from google.colab import drive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import gdown
import pandas as pd
import gdown
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

import pandas as pd
import gdown
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

import pandas as pd
import gdown
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

def get_prices() -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Замените ссылку ниже на вашу публичную ссылку на Google Диск
    file_url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1g_qdh6tM8vL9az0GD5ianzqvXZ-XnCqZ"

    # Задайте имя файла, под которым хотите сохранить его
    output_file = "EURUSD_H1_200001030000_202308021800.csv"

    # Скачиваем файл по ссылке
    gdown.download(file_url, output_file, quiet=False)

    # Прочитайте CSV-файл с помощью pandas
    p = pd.read_csv(output_file, delim_whitespace=True)
    pFixed = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'close', 'volume'])
    pFixed['time'] = pd.to_datetime(p['<DATE>'] + ' ' + p['<TIME>'], format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
    pFixed['close'] = p['<CLOSE>']
    pFixed['high'] = p['<HIGH>']
    pFixed['low'] = p['<LOW>']
    pFixed['open'] = p['<OPEN>']
    pFixed['volume'] = p['<TICKVOL>']
    pFixed.set_index('time', inplace=True)
    pFixed = pFixed.dropna()
    # Выбираем признаки для нормализации
    features_to_normalize = ['close','open','high','low','volume']

    # Создаем объект StandardScaler
    scaler = StandardScaler()

    # Применяем нормализацию к выбранным признакам
    pFixed[features_to_normalize] = scaler.fit_transform(pFixed[features_to_normalize])
    # Убедитесь, что вы не добавили дубликаты столбцов
    pFixed = pFixed.loc[:, ~pFixed.columns.duplicated()]

    # Возвращаем исходные данные с номерами кластеров
    return pFixed.dropna()


def find_local_min_max(prices, window=15):
    local_mins = (prices == prices.shift(-1).rolling(window=window, min_periods=1).min())
    local_maxs = (prices == prices.shift(-1).rolling(window=window, min_periods=1).max())
    return local_mins, local_maxs

def labelling_relabeling(dataset, min=7, max=17, relabeling=False):
    labels = []

    # Вызовем функцию для нахождения локальных минимумов и максимумов
    local_mins, local_maxs = find_local_min_max(dataset['close'])

    for i in range(dataset.shape[0]-max):
        rand = random.randint(min, max)
        curr_pr = dataset['close'][i]
        future_pr = dataset['close'][i + rand]

        if relabeling:
            m_labels = dataset['meta_labels'][i:rand+1].values

        if relabeling and 0.0 in m_labels:
            labels.append(2)
        else:
            if future_pr + MARKUP < curr_pr:
                labels.append(1)
            elif future_pr - MARKUP > curr_pr:
                labels.append(0)
            else:
                labels.append(2)

        # Добавляем метку "3.0" для локальных минимумов и "4.0" для локальных максимумов
        if local_mins[i]:
            labels[-1] = 3
        elif local_maxs[i]:
            labels[-1] = 4

    dataset = dataset.iloc[:len(labels)].copy()
    dataset['labels'] = labels
    dataset = dataset.dropna()
    dataset = dataset.drop(
        dataset[dataset.labels == 2].index)

    return dataset


    dataset = dataset.iloc[:len(labels)]
    dataset['labels'] = labels
    dataset = dataset.dropna()
    dataset = dataset.drop(
        dataset[dataset.labels == 2].index)

    return dataset

def tester(dataset: pd.DataFrame, markup=0.0, use_meta=False, plot=False):
    last_deal = int(2)
    last_price = 0.0
    report = [0.0]
    meta_labels = dataset['labels'].copy()

    for i in range(dataset.shape[0]):
        pred = dataset['labels'][i]
        meta_labels[i] = np.nan
        if use_meta:
            pred_meta = dataset['meta_labels'][i] # 1 = allow trades

        if last_deal == 2 and ((use_meta and pred_meta==1) or not use_meta):
            last_price = dataset['close'][i]
            last_deal = 0 if pred <= 0.5 else 1
            continue

        if last_deal == 0 and pred > 0.5 and ((use_meta and pred_meta==1) or not use_meta):
            last_deal = 2
            report.append(report[-1] - markup +
                          (dataset['close'][i] - last_price))
            if report[-1] > report[-2]:
                meta_labels[i] = 1
            else:
                meta_labels[i] = 0
            continue

        if last_deal == 1 and pred < 0.5 and ((use_meta and pred_meta==1) or not use_meta):
            last_deal = 2
            report.append(report[-1] - markup +
                          (last_price - dataset['close'][i]))
            if report[-1] > report[-2]:
                meta_labels[i] = 1
            else:
                meta_labels[i] = 0

    y = np.array(report).reshape(-1, 1)
    X = np.arange(len(report)).reshape(-1, 1)
    lr = LinearRegression()
    lr.fit(X, y)

    l = lr.coef_
    if l >= 0:
        l = 1
    else:
        l = -1

    if(plot):
        plt.plot(report)
        plt.plot(lr.predict(X))
        plt.title("Strategy performance R^2 " + str(format(lr.score(X, y) * l,".2f")))
        plt.xlabel("the number of trades")
        plt.ylabel("cumulative profit in pips")
        plt.show()

    return lr.score(X, y) * l, meta_labels.fillna(method='backfill')

def brute_force(dataset, pr_tst_test, bad_samples_fraction=0.5):
    # features for model\meta models. We learn main model only on filtered labels
    X = dataset[dataset['meta_labels']==1]
    X = dataset[dataset.columns[:-2]]
    X = X[X.index >= START_DATE]
    X = X[X.index <= STOP_DATE]

    X_meta = dataset[dataset.columns[:-2]]
    X_meta = X_meta[X_meta.index >= TSTART_DATE]
    X_meta = X_meta[X_meta.index <= STOP_DATE]

    # labels for model\meta models
    y = dataset[dataset['meta_labels']==1]
    y = dataset[dataset.columns[-2]]
    y = y[y.index >= START_DATE]
    y = y[y.index <= STOP_DATE]

    y_meta = dataset[dataset.columns[-1]]
    y_meta = y_meta[y_meta.index >= TSTART_DATE]
    y_meta = y_meta[y_meta.index <= STOP_DATE]

    # train\test split
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(
        X, y, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5, shuffle=True)

    # learn main model with train and validation subsets
    model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=40,
                               depth=4,
                               learning_rate=0.1,
                               eval_metric='Accuracy',
                               verbose=False,
                               use_best_model=False,
                               task_type='CPU')

    model.fit(train_X, train_y, eval_set=(test_X, test_y),
              early_stopping_rounds=10, plot=True)

    # Разбиение данных на обучение и валидацию
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5)

    # Обучение модели CatBoost с early stopping по метрике точности
    model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=30, task_type='CPU')
    model.fit(train_X, train_y, eval_set=(test_X, test_y), early_stopping_rounds=50, plot=False)

    # Кросс-валидация обученной модели
    kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kf)
    print("Кросс-валидация CatBoost: ", scores)

    # learn meta model with train and validation subsets
    meta_model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=40,
                                    depth=5,
                                    learning_rate=0.1,
                                    eval_metric='Accuracy',
                                    verbose=False,
                                    use_best_model=False,
                                    task_type='CPU')

    meta_model.fit(train_X, train_y, eval_set=(test_X, test_y),
              early_stopping_rounds=10, plot=True)

    # Кросс-валидация мета-модели
    kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
    scores = cross_val_score(meta_model, X_meta, y_meta, cv=kf)
    print("Кросс-валидация мета-модели:", scores.mean())

    # Предсказание на новых данных
    pr_tst = get_prices()
    X = pr_tst[pr_tst.columns[1:]]
    X.columns = [''] * len(X.columns)
    X_meta = X.copy()

    p = model.predict_proba(X)
    p_meta = meta_model.predict_proba(X_meta)
    # predict on new data (validation plus learning)
    pr_tst = get_prices()
    X = pr_tst[pr_tst.columns[1:]]
    X.columns = [''] * len(X.columns)
    X_meta = X.copy()

    # predict the learned models (base and meta)
    p = model.predict_proba(X)
    p_meta = meta_model.predict_proba(X_meta)

    p2 = [x[0] < 0.5 for x in p]
    p2_meta = [x[0] < 0.5 for x in p_meta]
    # Добавьте метки мета-модели к DataFrame pr_tst_test
    pr2_meta = pr_tst_test.iloc[:len(p2_meta)].copy()
    pr2_meta['meta_labels'] = p2_meta
    pr2_meta['vision_labels'] = p2_meta
    pr2 = pr_tst.iloc[:len(p2)].copy()
    pr2['labels'] = p2
    pr2['meta_labels'] = p2_meta
    pr2['labels'] = pr2['labels'].astype(float)
    pr2['meta_labels'] = pr2['meta_labels'].astype(float)
    full_pr = pr2.copy()
    pr2 = pr2[pr2.index >= TSTART_DATE]
    pr2 = pr2[pr2.index <= STOP_DATE]

    # add bad samples of this iteratin (bad meta labels)
    global BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK
    BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK = BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK.append(pr2[pr2['meta_labels']==0.0].index)

    # test mdels and resample meta labels
    R2, meta_labels = tester(pr2, MARKUP, use_meta=True, plot=False)
    pr2['meta_labels'] = meta_labels

    # resample labels based on meta labels
    pr2 = labelling_relabeling(pr2, relabeling=True)
    pr2['labels'] = pr2['labels'].astype(float)
    pr2['meta_labels'] = pr2['meta_labels'].astype(float)

    # mark bad labels from bad_samples_book
    if BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK.value_counts().max() > 1:
        to_mark = BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK.value_counts()
        mean = to_mark.mean()
        marked_idx = to_mark[to_mark > mean*bad_samples_fraction].index
        pr2.loc[pr2.index.isin(marked_idx), 'meta_labels'] = 0.0
    else:
        pr2.loc[pr2.index.isin(BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK), 'meta_labels'] = 0.0

    R2, _ = tester(full_pr, MARKUP, use_meta=True, plot=False)

    return [R2, model, meta_model, pr2]

def test_model(result: list):
    pr_tst = get_prices()
    X = pr_tst[pr_tst.columns[1:]]
    X.columns = [''] * len(X.columns)
    X_meta = X.copy()

    # test the learned model
    p = result[1].predict_proba(X)
    p_meta = result[2].predict_proba(X_meta)
    p2 = [x[0] < 0.5 for x in p]
    p2_meta = [x[0] < 0.5 for x in p_meta]
    pr2 = pr_tst.iloc[:len(p2)].copy()
    pr2['labels'] = p2
    pr2['meta_labels'] = p2_meta
    R2, meta_labels = tester(pr2, MARKUP, use_meta=True, plot=True)

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

import catboost
from google.colab import drive
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil  # Добавьте этот импорт

# make dataset
pr = get_prices()
pr = labelling_relabeling(pr, relabeling=False)
a, b = tester(pr, MARKUP, use_meta=False, plot=False)
pr['meta_labels'] = b
pr = pr.dropna()
pr = labelling_relabeling(pr, relabeling=True)

# Prepare image data for neural network and add 'vision_labels' to the dataset
def prepare_image_data(data, window_size):
    images = []
    labels = []
    for i in range(data.shape[0] - window_size):
        img = data.iloc[i:i + window_size]['close'].values
        images.append(img)
        label = data.iloc[i + window_size]['meta_labels']  # Используйте 'meta_labels' как метку
        labels.append(label)
        # Добавьте 'vision_labels' в набор данных
        data.loc[data.index[i + window_size], 'meta_labels'] = label
    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)


window_size = 15
X_images, y_labels = prepare_image_data(pr, window_size)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_images, y_labels, test_size=0.5, random_state=50)

def build_cnn(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
    x = Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

# Define the input shape based on the window size and number of features
input_shape = (window_size, 1)  # No need to add the batch size dimension for Conv1D
model = build_cnn(input_shape)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

vision_model = build_cnn(input_shape)
m_number=1

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

# Make predictions using the trained model
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

# Функция для сохранения и конвертации моделей CatBoost в ONNX
def export_model_to_ONNX(model, model_number, drive_path, SYMBOL):
    # Сохраните модель CatBoost в формате ONNX
    model[1].save_model(
        f"model{model_number}.onnx",
        format="onnx",
        export_parameters={
            'onnx_domain': 'ai.catboost',
            'onnx_model_version': 1,
            'onnx_doc_string': f'Model {model_number} for MultiClassification',
            'onnx_graph_name': f'CatBoostModel_{model_number}'
        }
    )
    model[2].save_model(
        f"metamodel{model_number}.onnx",
        format="onnx",
        export_parameters={
            'onnx_domain': 'ai.catboost',
            'onnx_model_version': 1,
            'onnx_doc_string': f'Meta Model {model_number} for MultiClassification',
            'onnx_graph_name': f'CatBoostMetaModel_{model_number}'
        }
    )

    # Монтируем Google Диск
    drive.mount('/content/drive')

    # Modify this line to point to your Google Drive directory
    onnx_model_path = os.path.join(drive_path, f'{SYMBOL}_model{model_number}.onnx')
    onnx_meta_model_path = os.path.join(drive_path, f'{SYMBOL}_metamodel{model_number}.onnx')

     # Переместите ONNX модели на Google Диск
    onnx_model_drive_path = os.path.join(drive_path, f'{SYMBOL}_model{model_number}.onnx')
    onnx_meta_model_drive_path = os.path.join(drive_path, f'{SYMBOL}_metamodel{model_number}.onnx')

    shutil.move(onnx_model_path, onnx_model_drive_path)
    shutil.move(onnx_meta_model_path, onnx_meta_model_drive_path)

    print(f'Models exported to ONNX format and saved on Google Drive:')
    print(f'ONNX model path: {onnx_model_drive_path}')
    print(f'ONNX meta model path: {onnx_meta_model_drive_path}')

# Пример вызова функции
drive_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/'
SYMBOL = 'your_symbol'  # Замените на нужное значение

# Загрузка данных и обработка
pr = get_prices()
pr = labelling_relabeling(pr, relabeling=False)
a, b = tester(pr, MARKUP, use_meta=False, plot=False)
pr['meta_labels'] = b
pr = pr.dropna()
pr = labelling_relabeling(pr, relabeling=True)

# make dataset
pr = get_prices()
pr = labelling_relabeling(pr, relabeling=False)
a, b = tester(pr, MARKUP, use_meta=False, plot=False)
pr['meta_labels'] = b
pr = pr.dropna()
pr = labelling_relabeling(pr, relabeling=True)
# Загрузка данных для тестирования
pr_tst_test = get_prices()  # Замените эту строку на код, который загружает данные для тестирования
# iterative learning
res = []
BAD_SAMPLES_BOOK = pd.DatetimeIndex([])
for i in range(3):
    try:
        # В вашем вызове функции brute_force добавьте аргумент pr_tst_test:
        res.append(brute_force(pr[pr.columns[1:]], pr_tst_test, bad_samples_fraction=0.5))
        print('Iteration: {}, R^2: {}'.format(i, res[-1][0]))
    except ValueError as e:
        # Обработка ошибки, например, вывод сообщения об ошибке
        print(f"Ошибка: {e}")
        # Можно пропустить итерацию и перейти к следующей
        continue

# test best model
res.sort()
p = test_model(res[-1])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_models(model, meta_model, vision_model, pr_tst, FSTOP_DATE, meta_labels):
    # Выберите данные для тестирования, начиная с STOP_DATE и заканчивая FSTOP_DATE
    pr_tst_test = pr_tst[pr_tst.index >= STOP_DATE]
    pr_tst_test = pr_tst_test[pr_tst_test.index <= FSTOP_DATE]

    # Загрузите данные для тестирования
    X = pr_tst_test[pr_tst_test.columns[1:]]
    X.columns = [''] * len(X.columns)
    X_meta = X.copy()

    # Добавьте столбец 'meta_labels' к 'pr_tst_test' (предполагая, что у вас есть данные в 'meta_labels')
    pr_tst_test['meta_labels'] = meta_labels

    # Используйте модель CatBoost для предсказания результатов на новых данных
    p_catboost = model.predict_proba(X)
    p2_catboost = [x[0] < 0.5 for x in p_catboost]

    # Создайте новый DataFrame с предсказаниями CatBoost
    pr2_catboost = pr_tst_test.iloc[:len(p2_catboost)].copy()
    pr2_catboost['labels'] = p2_catboost

    # Используйте мета-модель для предсказания меток на новых данных
    p_meta = meta_model.predict_proba(X_meta)
    p2_meta = [x[0] < 0.5 for x in p_meta]

    # Добавьте метки мета-модели к DataFrame
    pr2_meta = pr_tst_test.iloc[:len(p2_meta)].copy()
    pr2_meta['meta_labels'] = p2_meta

    # Подготовьте новые данные для тестирования компьютерного зрения
    new_vision_data = prepare_image_data(pr_tst_test, window_size)

    # Используйте модель компьютерного зрения для предсказания результатов на новых данных
    vision_predictions = vision_model.predict(new_vision_data)

    # Добавьте метки компьютерного зрения к DataFrame
    pr_tst_test['vision_labels'] = vision_predictions

    # Объедините предсказания всех моделей в один DataFrame
    combined_predictions = pd.concat([pr2_catboost, pr2_meta, pr_vision], axis=1)

    # Вызовите функцию tester для анализа результатов и оценки производительности всех моделей
    R2, meta_labels = tester(combined_predictions, MARKUP, use_meta=True, plot=True)

    return R2, meta_labels

# Определение и заполнение dataset
dataset = get_prices()

# Создать, обучить и скомпилировать модели в функции brute_force
model, meta_model, vision_model, pr2, meta_labels = brute_force(dataset, pr_tst_test, bad_samples_fraction=0.5)

pr_tst_test['meta_labels'] = meta_labels

# Вызовите функцию test_models и передайте созданные модели и метки meta_labels
R2_score, meta_labels = test_models(model, meta_model, vision_model, pr_tst, FSTOP_DATE, meta_labels)

# Результаты теперь содержат общий график и метки для всех моделей
print("Combined R^2 Score:", R2_score)
print("Combined Meta Labels:", meta_labels)

# Call the function with the modified path
export_model_to_ONNX(res[-1], str(1), drive_path, SYMBOL)`
```

Код ошибки:

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

5 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'meta_labels'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'meta_labels'`
```

Comment: Ошибку приведите полностью в вопросе

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести код поменьше, где так же будет присутствовать эта ошибка? Ошибка возникает потому что вы из `DataFrame` пытаетесь получить колонку `meta_labels`, а её там нет. На какой именно строчке произошла ошибка, не понятно. У вас этих строк 600. Хотя бы скажите где конкретно, на какой строчке, вылетает эта ошибка.

Comment: Трейс ошибки вы не полный привели, непонятно, в каком месте вашего кода эта ошибка выходит.

Comment: Ошибка возникает на этой строчке: # features for model\meta models. We learn main model only on filtered labels
    X = dataset[dataset['meta_labels']==1]. Получается, когда код до конца исполняется, и чтобы вызвать функцию test models, вызывается функция bruteforce

Comment: `= brute_force(dataset` - здесь `dataset = get_prices()`, а `get_prices` не заполняет колонку `'meta_labels'` - вот и выходит ошибка. Как это починить я не знаю, потому что у вас ну очень запутанный код и совершенно непонятно "кто на ком стоял" и что тут вообще происходит. Код скомпонован очень плохо, непонятно, какая функция что делает и почему по многу раз одни и те же функции вызываются, зачем столько однотипных переменных с разными названиями и т.д. Всё это нужно упорядочивать как-то, сейчас это сложно понять.

Comment: Возможно, достаточно будет просто в функции `get_prices` записать в колонку `'meta_labels'` хотя бы что-то, хоть нули. Но может быть это починит только ошибку, но не логику работы вашего кода.

Comment: Если колонку записать, вся логика ломается и еще новые ошибки выходят((((

Comment: Могу только посоветовать начать разбираться с кода поменьше/попроще. Такую простыню кода отлаживать - то ещё удовольствие. Пока вы не разберётесь где что и зачем тут происходит, можно только гадать, как это починить.